# Populate price range dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, price

I want to create a select between min to max using PHP.

For example I have this min price of 1000000 and the max is 40000000.

How can I generate something like this in PHP?

```
<select>
<option>1m<option>
<option>1.5m<option>
<option>2m<option>
<option>so on up to max price<option>
</select>
```

cheers

Comment: Why would  you generate something like that on server side with php? Just list the options or generate them with javascript on the client... but i would suggest using plain html if there isnt any other functionality involved.

Comment: the real-state property usually starts at 1m up to 45m. im just curious what if there's a user add a property with a price of 300k so i want it to populate dynamically based on min and max with step 250k

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php foreach(range(1,4,0.5) as $val): ?>
<option><?php echo($val.'m'); ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code :

```
<select>
<?php
  for($i=1;$i<=4;$i=$i+0.5)
  {
      echo '<option>'   . $i . 'm</option>';
  } 
?>
</select>
```